# combining different types of data from two tables into one column

Tags: excel, join

I have two Excel spreadsheets exported from different databases. SheetA has two columns: studentID and studentName. SheetB also has two columns: studentID and awardsEarned.

I want to combine these for a final deliverable using studentID as a matching key. I want studentName and awardsEarned to be in one column because I am pasting this into a document and handing it off for printing.

My deliverable needs to have a column that combines the two datasets like:

student 1

- award x
- award y
- award z

student 2

- award x
- award y

Further, I want to re-arrange the data so that I can have it by Award and then by student:

Award 1

- student 1
- student 2

Award 2

- student 1

etc.

This is more of relational database operation as as I understand it. I used to do this is FileMaker but cannot use it any longer. I want to find a way to do this in excel so I can create a process that does not require a database backend. Is this possible?

Comment: Combine both datasets in  a single one and then use Pivot Tables to get your desired output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Formula in dataset 2 to get Student Name is just VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(D5;$A$5:$B$8;2;FALSE)
```

Then create a Pivot Table to get the desired output. Just take fields Award and Student Name from dataset 2 into rows section.